# Android ListView items ID

Tags: android

I have implemented a class named Reciever which Extends Broadcast reciever...
what i want is that either to show the recieved sms in toast i want to send it in another java class wich is extends from Activity..here is the code of that class..

```
package com.sms.sms;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.telephony.SmsManager;
import android.telephony.SmsMessage;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Reciever extends BroadcastReceiver {
    final SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
    String msg="";
    String number="";
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent inn) 
    {
        Bundle bndl = inn.getExtras();
        try
        {
            if(bndl != null)
            {
                Object[] sms_details= (Object[]) bndl.get("pdus");
                for(int i=0 ; i<sms_details.length ; i++)
                {
                    SmsMessage message = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) sms_details[i]);
                     number = message.getDisplayOriginatingAddress();
                     msg = message.getDisplayMessageBody();
//                  Toast.makeText(arg0, "Sender Number = "+number+" Your Message = "+msg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                Intent in = new Intent();
                in.setAction("SMS_RECIEVED_ACTION");
                in.putExtra("msg", msg);
                in.putExtra("num", number);
                arg0.sendBroadcast(in);

            }
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            Toast.makeText(arg0, "Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

}
```

now i have another class named sms reciver which contain 2 edittexts in which i want to show these msgs...

```
package com.sms.sms;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class recieve_sms extends Activity {
    EditText edt_msg;
    Bundle bndl;
    Button btn_rply;
    EditText edt_num;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_recieve);
        edt_msg = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
        edt_num = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        btn_rply = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    //here should be some code which recieve msg from Reciever class and show in edittexts..    

    }

}
```

Comment: what is your question..

Answer (score 0):

**Assuming your broadcast receiver is working correctly and your variable `msg` and `number` are perfect too.**

**First option Show using Toast**:

Just add this after your `for`:

```
 Toast.makeText(context, msg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
```

**Second option Show on other activity**:

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(context, recieve_sms.class);
 intent.putExtra("msg", msg);
 intent.putExtra("num", number);
 startActivity(intent);
```

On `onCreate` of `recieve_sms`:

```
 Intent intent = getIntent();
 String number = intent.getStringExtra("num");
 String msg = intent.getStringExtra("msg");
```

Answer (score 0):

The simple code is you can do like this

```
package com.tcs.smsactivity;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.telephony.SmsMessage;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MySMSReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

String action,from,message;
public static final String SMS_RECEIVED_ACTION = "android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED";


@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

     action=intent.getAction();


    Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();        
        SmsMessage[] msgs = null;


        if(null != bundle)
        {
            Object[] pdus = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
            msgs = new SmsMessage[pdus.length];

            if(action.equals(SMS_RECEIVED_ACTION)){

                 for (int i=0; i<msgs.length; i++){
                        msgs[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[])pdus[i]);                
                        info += msgs[i].getOriginatingAddress();                    
                        info += "\n*****TEXT MESSAGE*****\n";
                        info += msgs[i].getMessageBody().toString();
                        from=msgs[i].getOriginatingAddress();
                        message=msgs[i].getMessageBody().toString();


                    }

            } 
           }

    Intent showMessage=new Intent(context, AlertMessage.class);
    showMessage.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    showMessage.putExtra("from", from);
    showMessage.putExtra("message", message);
    context.startActivity(showMessage);

}

}
```

Now inside your AlertMessage Activity class you can grab all the data and set in to the edit text :

**AlertMessage.java**

```
public class AlertMessage extends Activity{

String from,message;

private Bundle bundle;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.screen);


    bundle=getIntent().getExtras();

if(null!=bundle){
    from=bundle.getString("from");
    message=bundle.getString("message");

           // set the information in to edit text here  

      }
}
}
```